# swipeActionsでitemのアトリビュートを変更時の、引数のIndexSetに指定するプロパティ

Tags: xcode, swiftui

`swipeActions` で item の Bool を変更したいのですが、選択する item の IndexSet の指定はどのようにすればいいですか？

以下のようにして、`deleteItems(offsets: indexSet)` の部分での indexSet に
`let indexSet: IndexSet = IndexSet()` としましたが、変更されません。

```swift
}.swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
    Button {
        deleteItems(offsets: indexSet)
    } label: {Image(systemName: "trash")}
}
```

```swift
    func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
         withAnimation {
             offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach{$0.bool.toggle()}

             do {
                 try viewContext.save()
             } catch {
                 let nsError = error as NSError
                 fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
             }
         }
     }
```

以下のように記述するとエラーになります。

```swift
ForEach(items, id: \.self){item in
Text(item.text ?? "a")
}

}.swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
    Button {
    item.bool.toggle()
    } label: {Image(systemName: "trash")}
}
```